# Json file contains key names that begin with $

Tags: json

I have a `json` file which looks something like [this](http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema).

It contains various things like `"$schema"` and `"$ref"` for key names.

What does it mean when a key name begins with `$`?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.

`"$schema"` and `"$ref"` are simply valid JSON keys like any other key. They mean exactly as much and as little as `"foo"` or `"bar"` or `` "G@p)EH7=70~6<+u8~PRBu},mL)b'faTw=H7g_uCAr01_88oO[@It+0?`S7ZQm:]^" `` mean: absolutely nothing.

JSON does not ascribe meaning to anything. It is a pure data serialization format.

It is up to the *user* of the JSON document to ascribe meaning to the document.

In this particular case, it is possible that the user of the document is using [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) to validate the document, but it is equally possible that the user of the document is using those keys for something completely different. JSON doesn't care either way, and there is no Intergalactic JSON Police Department that tells you which keys you are allowed to interpret in which way.

In other words: if you want to know what those keys mean, you have to ask the person who created that document. JSON Schema is a good bet, though, since it is gaining popularity and is using exactly those two keys with exactly that spelling.

*Iff* we are to assume that those keys are used for JSON Schema, they mean (roughly) the following:

- [`$ref`](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#ref): references the schema to be used for this (sub-)document
- [`$schema`](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.1.1): identifies a JSON Schema